# Gunicorn Workers Failed to Boot after adding user permissions

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I've been trying to deploy a django project with gunicorn and nginx. I got everything working, except when I tried to upload a photo, I got Erno 13: Permission denied. I found this question on SO: [Django [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/media/animals/user_uploads'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797372/django-errno-13-permission-denied-var-www-media-animals-user-uploads), and I followed the advice on there regarding adding a group for user www-data, then giving permissions. After doing this, I can no longer run gunicorn. I get     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR) gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3

I've been using sudo /opt/myenv/bin/gunicorn -c /opt/myenv/myproject/gunicorn_config.py my_Site.wsgi to launch and up until now, it's been working fine.