# django 1.10 media image not showing up

Tags: django, django-1.10

I am unable to display images uploaded by the admin user through admin on a template.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

import web.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', web.views.home, name='home')
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

page.html

```
<img src="{{ event.image.url }}" alt="{{ event.title }}" />
```

also tried

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ event.image.url }}" alt="{{ event.title }}" />
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Thanks for your help.

--------------UPDATE--------------

[image: django project structure]

Comment: What is the output of `{{ event.image.url }}`? Does it show the relative path you would expect?

Comment: /media/images/events/old.jpg is what I get. Yes the path is correct.

Comment: let me know about your three path project... and where your project is running now? deployed at server or under local development?  My previous project is similiar with your case that deployed under server.. one reason is because permissions of path project, also the files. and fixes with changed that permissions such as `chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/yourproject`, `644` for the files, or other else..

Comment: I just think, if your configuration is look good, maybe you having a problem that related with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797372/django-errno-13-permission-denied-var-www-media-animals-user-uploads). As a side note, if you check at the browser a full path of your image, an example: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/events/old.jpg` and having permission denied.

Comment: I am on a windows machine, permissions shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar please update your question and let me know about your tree path project..

Comment: @SancaKembang updated. Please have a look.

Comment: if you change `import web.views` to `from web.views import home` and then  change `web.views.home` to `home`, what happend?

Comment: No change, still cant load. I didn't think it would make any difference.

Comment: In the terminal django is showing 200 OK for image calls.

Answer (score -1):

I had change the home path to remove the regex which was causing the routing to match it before the media url.

```
    url(r'', web.views.home, name='home')
```