# Django [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/media/'

Tags: django, apache

I can not add a comment to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797786/6143954.

So I created a new question.

It was the correct answer before it was edited. In this answer, the line

```
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/
```

is replaced by

```
sudo chmod -R 760 /var/www/
```

Specifically, this solution is not suitable for Django.

The answer should not be changed after it has been marked as the right solution.

That was the correct answer before correcting the original post.

```
The GOOD solution would be:

sudo groupadd varwwwusers
sudo adduser www-data varwwwusers
sudo chgrp -R varwwwusers /var/www/
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/
```

How correct is this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/` is fine.
This means that owner and group has all rights and others don't have any rights.
This is right way.
If you set 760, group users will get Permission denied on read or write attempts.

For files inside directory you can set them as 760.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. That "sudo chmod -R 770 / var / www /" is the right solution. So this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797786/6143954 can not accept as the right solution. And leads other users to delusion.

Comment: Helpful. and useful