# Django with Mod_WSGI on ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2 Permission denied for media/

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to deploy my Django(1.10) project on Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache2 using Mode_WSGI

I have set up my project folder inside `home` as `Fetchors` directory and add permissions to it as:

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 6 abdul abdul    4096 Feb 10 15:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root     4096 Feb 11 04:40 ..
-rw------- 1 abdul abdul    3930 Feb 11 02:14 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 abdul abdul     220 Apr  4  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 abdul abdul    3771 Apr  4  2018 .bashrc
drwx------ 3 abdul abdul    4096 Feb 10 15:37 .cache
drwx------ 3 abdul abdul    4096 Feb 10 15:34 .gnupg
-rw-r--r-- 1 abdul abdul     807 Apr  4  2018 .profile
drwx------ 2 abdul abdul    4096 Feb 10 15:34 .ssh
drwxrwxr-x 9 abdul www-data 4096 Feb 11 06:27 Fetchors
```

And here are the permissions inside `media` directory:

```
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 abdul www-data 4096 Feb 10 15:37 .
drwxrwxr-x 9 abdul www-data 4096 Feb 11 06:27 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 abdul www-data 4096 Feb 10 15:37 driver_image
drwxrwxr-x 2 abdul www-data 4096 Feb 10 15:46 product_image
```

I'm creating a proudct object which need to save the product image inside `product_image` folder but it says:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'media/product_image'

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you given permission to `media` folder in `.conf` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: '/var/www/media/animals/user\_uploads'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797372/django-errno-13-permission-denied-var-www-media-animals-user-uploads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing my `MEDIA_ROOT` path in `settings.py` as:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Then, it will grab the appropriate permissions of the Project.

Answer (score 2):

Give permission to your media folder by running this command in the terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 777 media
```

but this is a bad solution follow the advice on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797786/5301788