# "Permission denied" Error in Django Application Deployed on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Django project (`MyProj`) to Amazon beanstalk using the eb CLI. This project is physically located at `~/MyProj`. It has an app, named `myapp`, which needs to execute external python scripts. For this purpose, I have `my_launcher.py` in `~/MyProj/myapp` directory. A code snippet in `my_launcher.py is`:

```python
import os
import importlib

PROJECTS_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser(os.environ.get('LOCATION')), 'app/python/')

MY_MODULE = os.path.join(PROJECTS_DIR, 'MyModule/my_script.py')
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('my_script', My_MODULE)
MyModule = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(MyModule)
```

The reason for using the environment variable `LOCATION` is to dynamically set the location of external python scripts. I have defined this environment variable and some others through the AWS admin console under the Elastic Beanstalk section. In my example, I have:

```
LOCATION = '/home/ec2-user/company/'
```

This script fails at the last line with the error:

```
PermissionError at /myapp
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ec2-user/company/app/python/MyModule/my_script.py'
```

The things I have done so far to no avail:

1. After reading many online pages (e.g., [Django [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/media/animals/user_uploads'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797372/django-errno-13-permission-denied-var-www-media-animals-user-uploads)), I thought the issue is Linux permissions on the location where the executable python scripts are (i.e., `/home/ec2-user/company/app/python/`). For the sake of testing this hypothesis (even though I know it is a bad approach for production), I ran the command `sudo chmod -R 777 company` while being in `/home/ec2-user` directory. I redeployed the project and even rebooted the EC2 instance all together. This didn't help.
2. I moved the `company` directory inside `~/MyProj/myapp` (and updated the environment variable `LOCATION` on the server) thinking that the `wsgi` user does not have execution permission on any directory outside `~/MyProj/myapp`. This didn't help.

I highly appreciate any help.

By the way, I am using python 3.6 and Django 2.1.7.