# DJANGO 4.1 manage.py invalid syntax when trying to run collectstatic

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-manage.py, collectstatic

**Project Folder Structure**

-Project
--app1
--app2
--static

static folder has all static files for all apps.

**Settings.py**

```
try:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
except KeyError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("Could not find a SECRET_KEY in enviroment") from e

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/191.96.1.180/static"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'static/')
```

**ERROR:**
File "manage.py", line 17
) from exc
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**pip list:**
[pip list 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ifL7.png)
[pip list 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G16BB.png)

So. My problem is when running `python manage.py collectstatic` on the developement server on my local machine it works. it saves all static files on the path from settings.py
when i try to run `python manage.py collectstatic` on my linux server i get this error.
It is not due to python version or django version i have checked.

**What I've tried and the errors:**

So when i try running those commands thats what i get.

**python manage.py runserver**

`Runs`

**python3 manage.py runserver**

`Runs`

if i try 
**sudo python manage.py runserver**
`INVALID SYNTAX`

**sudo python3 manage.py runserver** 
`Can't find DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`
( I have gotten the secret key variable |  source ~/.DJANGO_SECRET_KEY )

**python manage.py collectstatic** 
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/191.96.1.180'

**python3 manage.py collectstatic**
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/191.96.1.180'

**sudo python manage.py collectstatic**
INVALID SYNTAX

**sudo python3 manage.py collectstatic** 
Can't find Secret Key

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `python3`:

```bash
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I edited the post if you wanna take a look. 
already tried it with python 3

Comment: `Can't find DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` -  have you checked your secret key in settings?

Comment: Yes i have and the secret_key is there, I would not be able to make it run with runserver , if key was absent

Comment: try:
  SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
 except KeyError as e:
  raise RuntimeError("Could not find a SECRET_KEY in enviroment") from e

and secret key is in enviroment variable

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797786/16475089

Comment: I just tried it , still says permission denied. with python3 and if i try it with sudo python3 it says 'Could not find a SECRET_KEY in enviroment' but i have gotten the key with 'source ~/DJANGO_SECRET_KEY'... I really dont know what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, The main reason it was throwing errors was permissions.

needed to add `www-data` as owner of permissions to the whole path for staticfiles

`var/www/`